# MySQL query filtering

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I'm working with prestashop 1.6.0.9

I'm using the getFirstMessage() function which will return the message by the system or a customer if they send one to display on the invoice. However, I'm struggling with the SQL of it here.

```
<?php

Class Order extends OrderCore {
    public function getFirstMessage()
    {
        return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('
            SELECT `message`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'message`
            WHERE `id_order` = '.(int)$this->id.'
            ORDER BY `id_message`
        ');
    }
}
```

When a customer orders something, the default messages set are things like 'payment accepted' or 'payment error'.

I wish to make it so it does not return a message if the message is 'payment accept' so I did this.

```
<?php

Class Order extends OrderCore {
    public function getFirstMessage()
    {
        return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('
            SELECT `message`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'message`
            WHERE (`id_order` = '.(int)$this->id.')
            AND (`message` != "Payment accepted")
            ORDER BY `id_message`
        ');
    }
}
```

But that didn't work as it still returned 'payment accepted', so then I tried this.

```
<?php

Class Order extends OrderCore {
    public function getFirstMessage()
    {
        $sql_val =  Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('
            SELECT `message`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'message`
            WHERE (`id_order` = '.(int)$this->id.')
            AND (`message` != "Payment accepted")
            ORDER BY `id_message`
        ');

        if(
            $sql_val == "Payment accepted"
        ) 
        {
            return "No Message";
        } else {
            return $sql_val;
        }
    }
}
```

That failed too. So now I'm here wanting some suggestions on how I can handle this?

Comment: maybe your problem is just the case sensitive, try `(\`message\` != 'payment accepted')` also, use single quotes, not double quotes with strings

Comment: that's how the message is in the database, Just a captial P. Also, I can't use single quotes as then Payment accepted would become part of a concatenation, which would then throw an error because it's supposed to be a string

Comment: You can and should use single quotes. because double quotes on sql means that you are using a field name. Try this way: `(\`message\` != \'Payment accepted\')`.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. However, still it outputs payment accepted if there is no other message by a customer. How can I stop it returning anything or 'no messages' if payment accepted is the only message available?

Comment: With this condition it should return anything at all if the only message is Payment accepted. Then, if the variable `$sql_val` is empty you can consider it as `no message` .

Comment: I strongly recommend using DbQuery class to build SELECT queries

Answer (score 0):

If I can suggest you a solution, string comparison is 'always' a magic trick, so I would do in this way:

```
<?php
public function getFirstMessage()
{
    $sql_val = strtolower(parent::getFirstMessage());
    if(!strcmp($sql_val, 'payment accepted')){ // 
        // do stuff
    }
    else {
        // do other stuff
    }  
}
```